# Invocation of methods with default parameters in scala higher-order function

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions, default-parameters

Supposedly I have a method that has one default parameter. I want to pass it as an argument to another method. How do I call the passed-in method with its default parameter ?

```
def printNum(i: Int = 4): Unit = {
  println(i)
}

def doStuff(printFunc: (Int) => Unit): Unit = {
  // How to call printFunc with its default parameter 
  printFunc()
}

doStuff(printNum)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you cannot. Default parameter is property of methods, just like named arguments and things like this. When you pass it as a function, it get's converted to function with eta expansion and functions don't have default parameters.

Just look at this:

```
def doStuff(printFunc: Int => Unit): Unit = ???
```

It is a method that expects function `Int => Unit`, any function `Int => Unit`. So if you can pass arbitrary function, how compiler would know that it has a default parameter.

You could think of creating a wrapper for `Function` that has a default value and overloaded `apply` method. But it's still not easy to pull out the default argument from method to make it transparent.

What you can easly do is create another method

```
def printDefaultNum(): Unit = {
  printNum(4)
}
```

And make `doStuff` accept `Function0` as you actually want to call it with no parameters.

```
def doStuff(printFunc: () => Unit): Unit = {
  printFunc()
}

doStuff(printDefaultNum)
```